# Is there any dependance between magento version and magento-cloud configuration?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cloud

This code in `composer.json` works for me:

```
"require": {
        "magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.1.4", "magento/magento-cloud-configuration": "101.4.0-dev"
},
```

Should I care about `magento-cloud-configuration` property if I want to switch to `magento 2.1.7` when it will be available and where to find the number of corresponding cloud configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You should rely on `magento/magento-cloud-metapackage` as specified in the [cloud template](https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud/blob/master/composer.json#L17). The version of `magento/magento-cloud-metapackage` is identical to that of `magento/product-enterprise-edition`. Internally, the metapackage consists of `magento/product-enterprise-edition` as well as appropriate `magento/magento-cloud-configuration` (referred to as MCC) required, so you don't have to worry about which is the corresponding MCC. For example, for `2.1.4`, `magento/magento-cloud-metapackage` is defined as:

```
{
     "name": "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage",
     "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Cloud Enterprise Edition)",
     "version": "2.1.4",
     "type": "metapackage",
     "require": {
         "magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.1.4",
         "magento/magento-cloud-configuration": "101.4.*"
     },
     "license": [
         "proprietary"
     ]
}
```

With this approach, if there is a cloud specific release (for example 101.4.1), you will be able to get it automatically via composer update.

To answer your original question (from soon to be published documentation)

> There is a many-to-one relationship between MCC version and Magento EE
>   versions. For Magento EE version `2.<X>.<Y>`, this package will have
>   versions matching: `<100 + X>.<Y>.*`. For example, Magento EE 2.3.4
>   would be associated with MCC 103.4.0. Then, a new version of MCC could
>   be released that corresponds to the same Magento EE version, and it
>   would be 103.4.1. This could be to add a new patch or to improve the
>   hooks.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification Maddy. From your response of snippet of pre-release documentation. I hope it would be appropriate for me to ask a side question of why magento-cloud-metapackage (2.2.2) requires `"magento/module-paypal-on-boarding": "100.2.*"` as one of its dependency when I'm not quite sure if this module has anything to do with the infrastructure? Thank you.